# How to use the generated classes after Xcode did "Class Definition" for Core Data?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 and I choose Class Definition for example Entity in a new project.

[image]

I can't seem to reference the generated class. Even after I press build

```
let x = Project()
Use of unresolved identifier 'Project'
```

Comment: Not sure what is going on but what I always do if I have changed the Core Data model and get some strange behavior afterwards is that I clean the project and build again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't reproduce. I created a new vanilla Single View app with Core Data direct from the template and made one Entity just like yours:

[image]

Then I added one line of code to the view controller's `viewDidLoad`; it compiles just fine:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let _ = Project()
    }

}
```

In a situation like yours, it is good to think about *how* this works. The code generation literally generates code. You can *see* that code by Control-clicking on the word `Project` and choosing Jump To Definition:

```
//  Project+CoreDataClass.swift
//  
//
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
//

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Project)
public class Project: NSManagedObject {

}
```

If you don't see something like that, quit Xcode, delete the contents of the DerivedData folder, open the project again, wait for indexing to finish, and try again.

If it *still* doesn't work, then switch Codegen to Manual/None in the model editor and generate the file manually:

[image]

After working your way through the dialogs, you'll see the generated files directly right in your project navigator:

[image]

At that point your project will definitely compile!

Comment: I guess auto code generation for core data model sometimes doesn't work well. It seems compiler cannot figure out where the generated model classes are and fail to refer to, even build successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (using Xcode 14.2), in that the compiler could not find the automatically generated class when setting Codegen = Class Definition.  The problem went away when I closed and re-opened the project.

Comment: reopen the project works for me too, surprise...