# Why entity defined in Core DataModel can not be used?

Tags: swift, xcode

I was using Xcode to generate an entity in Core DataModel of my project, and added 'words' as a property to the entity 'Item' then build completed successfully.

[image]

The entity however can not be referred to in ViewController as below

```
let myItem = Item()
```

Xcode marked Item as unresolved identifier， I'm not sure what else I should do?

Comment: Can you show the actual error.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871461/how-to-use-the-generated-classes-after-xcode-did-class-definition-for-core-dat ? See my answer there.